# What does `window.jqueryFoo = false;` mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

For context I saw it in a react component that

```js
export default class pageWithModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    window.jqueryFoo = false;

    this.state = {
      modal: false,
      value: ''
    };
  }

  handleModalOpen = () => {...};

  handleModalClose = () => {...};

  render()...
```

What does it do? Google search didn't find anything similar

Comment: `I saw it in a react component` is that the only reference to `jqueryOn` in the component?

Comment: yes one and only in the whole codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that a variable named `jqueryOn`, within the global context of the window, was set to false.